# How to create a submenu in Joomla! frontend

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

What I'm trying to do is create a submenu (in Joomla! backend) with below code but it does not work.

```
JSubMenuHelper::addEntry(JText::_('test'), 'index.php?option=com_test&controller=test', $controller == 'testcon');
```

I have attacted a sample pictures here. It explains what type of menu I want.

[sample menu is here. check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibp6g.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: can't you just create a submenu using the Menu Manager?

Comment: It's for front-end not the back-end. Please refer the screenshot attached

Comment: ah ok fair enough. which file are you adding this code to?

Comment: I'm adding it to the php. test.php(give that component name is com_test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSubMenuHelper is designed to be used in the Joomla! Administrator section, it's not made for the frontend.

If you really want to get to it, you need to include the file:

```
/administrator/includes/toolbar.php
```

Also you will have a bunch of missing CSS (js maybe also) files that you also need to include (form the admin template folder)

**But I see no reasons what you want to use JSubMenuHelper in front-end. I would strongly advise against using it.**

Comment: Please refer the screenshot attached. I want to add backed sub menu. Not frond-end

Answer (score 0):

You should create menu and (submenu) in Admin Panel, but I think you already know that :)
Later you add look and feel with CSS.
I think you should do ti with CSS not PHP.

Comment: It's for front-end not the back-end. Please refer the screenshot attached